# Optimization of expected value of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Z is random variable assuming integer values `n1,n2,..nM` with ni>0 for every i=1,2..,M

PMF qof z `p1,p2,...,pM`

Problem: Maximize E(Z)=summation varying from 1 to M(ni*pi)

[where P(Z=ni) = pi ]

Subject to the condition that summation varying from 1 to M(ni)=L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that we are **given** the $p_i$, and can choose the $n_i$, as long as the $n_i$ are positive integers, with $n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_M=L$.

Let $m$ be the index for which $p_m$ is largest.

Let $i$ be such that $p_i\lt p_m$. Then decreasing $n_i$ by $1$ (if allowed) and increasing $n_m$ by $1$ will leave the sum $L$ unchanged, and will increase the expectation.

If $p_i=p_m$, where $i\ne m$, decreasing $n_i$ by $1$ and increasing $n_m$ by $1$ will not change the expectation.

Thus for maximum expectation, let $n_i=1$ if $i\ne m$, and let $n_m=L-(M-1)$.

The sum of the $p_i$ with $i\ne m$ is $1-p_m$.

So the maximum value of the expectation is $(1)(1-p_m)+(L-M+1)p_m$.

This can be simplified to $1+(L-M)p_m$.

Comment: I got it...thanks for your great help. Can we solve using some other approach by means of vector optimization. If you have any idea or suggestion, please share it.

Comment: When the probabilities $p_i$ are given, I can't think of a substantially different approach, because of the integers restriction.